# java : can not find out the problem with could not find or load main class

Tags: java

Here is the main class:

```
public class TestAbstractFactory{
    public static void main(String []args){
        String [] creatros = {"ConcreteCreatorA", "ConcreteCreatorB"};
        try{
            int choice = Integer.parseInt("0");
            //----------
            //Creator c = Creator)Class.forName(creatros[choice]).newInstance();
            //Creator c = new ConcreteCreatorA();
            //----------
            c.anOperation();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Problem Encoutered");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Result 1 (Creator c = (Creator)Class.forName(creators[choice]).newInstance();):

Problem Encoutered

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ConcreteCreatorA

---

Result 2 (Creator c = new ConcreteCreatorA();):

Product Created : ConcreteProductA

*This result is expected.

---

So the question is that why I run fail in first program but work in second program to get my expected outcome?

Comment: It's awfully hard to tell without seeing all of the code, but I would ***guess*** `ConcreteCreatorA` is in a package.

Comment: my best guess ConcreteCreatorA is in a package

Comment: Thanks for answer, those class is already in the same directory. whatever with or without package, it still get the same outcome.

Comment: Try the full class name, with any namespace included.

Comment: Formatted code block.

Comment: Could you please post the whole code including imports and package declaration.

Comment: Thanks all, I already found out the problem and got done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Class.forName("className") should be called with the the fully qualified name of the desired class. See javadoc of the Class.forName